# What field does this Eigenvalue belong to?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose  $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a Vector Space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Given a Linear Operator *T* : $\mathbb{C}^n$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}^n$, it follows that $\lambda$ is an Eigenvalue of  *T* if and only if there exists some nonzero vector ***x*** $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^n$  such that *T*(***x***) = $\lambda$***x***.

My question is, exactly what field does $\lambda$ belong to? Does $\lambda$ belong to $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: what do you want for it to belong to?

Comment: Did you mean $\lambda$ is an Eigen*value*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the notice. I've corrected it.

Comment: @Exodd My question basically is; since my Vector Space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is over $\mathbb{R}$, I was wondering if my Eigenvalue(s) would be restricted to this condition.

Comment: If the vector space is over $R$ from what I remember you can only multiply vectors by scalars over $R$ so $\lambda v$ does not make sense if $v$ belongs to a vector space over $R$ and $\lambda$ is complex

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much for your answer. That is what I'm actually leaning toword as well. However, there is also some form of contradiction that I've encountered if $\lambda$ were to be able to take complex numbers. If you don't mind, could you have a look at the comment I made under linkja's answer? I'm not quite sure if I'm correct about that either.

Comment: By definition, eigenvalues are scalars. That means they are elements of the field over which you are considering the vector space. Note that the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a completely different object from the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at $\mathbb C^n$ as a $\mathbb R$-vectorspace the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has to be from $\mathbb R$, thats how it is defined. If $T$ is $\mathbb R$-linear it doesn't even have to be $\mathbb C$-linear, so it wouldn't even be a well defined question.

If you then look at maps that are also $\mathbb C$-linear you can say that the map comes from multiplication with an element $(\phi,r)$ from $\mathbb C$ this then corresponds to turn by $\phi$ and dilation by $r$ of the complex "Eigenvector" corresponding to $a+bi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a follow-up question to your answer. 

From a Textbook that I've read, it follows that
***x*** $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^n$ is an Eigenvector of *T* corresponding to $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if [***x***]$_B$ is an Eigenvector of [*T*]$_B$ corresponding to $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Now, in the book, their proof of this involves the property that [$\lambda$ ***x***]$_B$ = $\lambda$ [***x***]$_B$. However, given    [$\lambda$ ***x***]$_B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ (since my Vector Space is over $\mathbb{R}$) but $\lambda$ [***x***]$_B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^n$, how exactly does this equality hold?

Comment: btw 

(1) *B* is some Ordered Basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$

(2) for the term "my Vector Space is over $\mathbb{R}$", I mean my Vector Space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I completely didn't see the vector space being over $\mathbb R$, then of course Eigenvalues can only be from $R$ but the multiplication by scalars from $\mathbb C$ is still well defined

Comment: What do you mean by $[x]_B$ and $[T]_B$?

Comment: [ ***x*** ]$_B$ is the Coordinate Vector of  ***x*** relative to the Basis *B* while [*T*]$_B$ is the Matrix Representation of *T* with respect to the Basis *B*.

But yeah, if $\lambda$ can only take real values as you've newly suggested, then the problem I stated above should be resolved already.

Comment: the stretching and turning i described could be what they are talking about in the book, but I would have to think about it a bit more. Which book have you found that in?

Comment: Linear Algebra, 4th Edition by Stephen H. Friedberg. If you're reading via Pdf, then it is in the last paragraph of pages 266 to 267. For the actual page, it's pages 251-252.

Comment: I think this just refers to the isomorphism from a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$ into $F^n$ and that the linear map is diagonal if the induced linear map on the coordinates is linear

Comment: Yeah. I understand that. It's just that the proof would have a contradiction if $\lambda$ could be in $\mathbb{C}$ (for the case that I'm considering i.e. $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$) as you've previously suggested. But now, with your new answer, there shouldn't be any issues anymore. Anyways, thank you very much for your answer :>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other good points made in comments and answer: yes, there is some ambiguity in the idea of "eigenvalue" for linear maps/operators on vector spaces over fields (such as $\mathbb R$) that are not algebraically closed. And we should not get distracted by the idea that $\mathbb C^n$ can be a vector space over $\mathbb R$... that is mostly a distraction, without genuine mathematical content.

For example, consider operator $T=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr 1&0}$ on $\mathbb R^2$. If we look at the characteristic equation $\lambda^2+1=0$, we see that there are no real eigenvalues. But $\pm i$ *are* eigenvalues... if we extend the vector space to its *complexification*...

(Choosing a basis also doesn't really have much to do with this phenomenon...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Nice input. If you have some time, could you expand on the last sentence, i.e. the relation with choosing a basis? By complexification do you mean something like field extension? Sorry just curious :)

Comment: @Thomas, yes, "complexification" of a real vector space is a special case of "extending scalars" on a vector space over a field $k$ to a field extension $K$ of $k$. This can be expressed via bases (e.g., the extension of scalars of $k^n$ from $k$ to $K$ is $K^n$...), but also has an intrinsic sense, at a little more sophisticated level. Also... eigenvalues do not depend on choice of basis...